# Pegar usuário em query e adicionar variável no e-mail

Tags: php, codeigniter

Preciso pegar a informação USUÁRIO da tabela MySQL e enviar ele junto ao e-mail.

Como eu faço para adicionar junto a Query para pegar a informação da tabela usuário e criar a variável `$usuario` para incluir lá embaixo junto com o `.$newpass`?

Já tentei `->where("email = '{$email}', usuario = '{$usuario}'");` mas não obtive exito.

O site é feito em CodeIgniter.

```
public function generateNewPass()
{
    $email = $_POST["email"];


    $Query = Doctrine_Query::create()->from("Model_Usuarios f")
            ->where("email = '{$email}'");
    $existentEmail = $Query->execute(null,Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);        

    $response = array();

    if(empty($existentEmail)){
        $response["error"] = "y";
        $response["message"] = "E-mail não cadastrado.";
        echo json_encode($response);exit;
    }

    $newPass = $this->generatePassword();

    $table = DoctrineLib::gettable("Model_Usuarios");
    $mUser = $table->findOneById($existentEmail[0]["id"]);

    $mUser->senha = sha1($newPass);
    $mUser->save();


    //Altera senha do servidor, mesmo não logado no sistema
    $Planos = new Planos(true);
    $Planos->getUser($existentEmail[0]["id"]);
    $Planos->getServer();

    if ($Planos->hasServer()){
        $Planos->updateUser($newPass);
    }

    $response["error"] = "n";
    $response["message"] = "Erro ao recuperar senha, por favor contate o suporte.";

    if($this->sendNewPassMail($newPass, $email)){
        $response["error"] = "n";
        $response["message"] = "Uma nova senha foi enviada para " . $email;
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
}

private function sendNewPassMail($newPass, $email){

    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'mail.xxx.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'xxx@xxx.net',
        'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
        'mailtype'  => 'html', 
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
    );

    $this->load->library('email', $config);

    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from('xxx@xxx.net', 'xxx');
    $this->email->to($email);

    $this->email->subject(' Senha de acesso');
    $this->email->message("Sua nova senha de acesso - ".$newPass);

    if($this->email->send()){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente não há nada de errado no seu código. A variável $existentEmail já deve ter o retorno de todas as colunas da tabela Model_Usuarios com o e-mail especificado.

No código você só está tratando a identificação do ID aparentemente. Se você der um var_dump na variável $existentEmail provavelmente irá ver que ele vai possuir todas as colunas.

Tente criar uma variável com a seguinte sintaxe:

```
$usuario = $existentEmail[0]["usuario"];
```

O nome da chave deve ser o nome da coluna.

Comment: Olá Vinicisu, obrigado por comentar aqui na minha duvida! Sou meio novo nisso, estou tentando alterar o código de um site que possuo (considero uma alteração simples e me cobraram absurdos para fazer ela....) Acho que fiz o var_dump corretamente e ele me retornou "array(0) { }" Coloquei o código https://hastebin.com/anuxuromik.xml na página que eu recupero o e-mail. Está correto isso?

Comment: @IagoSouza só para confirmar, o script da funcionalidade que postou hoje funciona normalmente certo?

Qual a estrutura desse banco 'Model_Usuarios' sabe me informar? Pode me ajudar a tentar solucionar essa questão, pois na teoria seu código está correto e esse retorno significa que não encontrou nenhum usuário com o e-mail especificado.

Comment: funciona sim, quando eu digito o e-mail na área do site destinada para essa parte do código e clico em OK é enviado um e-mail com a nova senha gerada pelo sistema. O que eu gostaria de fazer é a partir do e-mail definir o usuário para enviar junto com a nova senha (alguns usuários não lembram o username para login e dizem que o sistema de recuperar senha não funciona). A estrutura do Model_Usuarios é essa: https://hastebin.com/tapafoyeja.xml